# Confusion about domains in PDE and "every $C^k$ manifold can be thought of as a smooth manifold"

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

I have read that every $C^k$ domain can be described instead by $C^\infty$ chart maps. So in this sense every $C^k$ domain is a $C^\infty$ domain. But consider standard PDE where people say thing like "Let $\Omega$ be a bounded $C^1$ domain and consider on it the heat equation..."

In this case, $\partial\Omega$ is a $C^1$ hypersurface. Why not people just say "let $\Omega$ be a $C^\infty$ domain", if the chart maps can be smooth for every $C^1$ domain?

Comment: I think the point is that every $C^k$ manifold admits **some** $C^\infty$ (sub)atlas. But what we want/mean when we talk about a $C^k$ domain in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is that the boundary of the domain considered as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ with the smooth structure induced by $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a $C^k$ manifold. This means that there are charts which are $C^\infty$ when considered relative to this sub atlas, but when we consider the chart $\phi :U \to \partial V$ as a map $\phi : U \to \Bbb{R}^n$, this map will not (necessarily) be smooth.

Comment: @PhoemueX -- Not every $C^k$-manifold admits a $C^\infty$ structure. Consider, for example, [this $C^0$-manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold).

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow: With $C^k$ i mean $C^k$ with $k \geq 1$ in this context. And if I remember correctly, every such manifold admits a $C^\infty$ atlas. I will look up the source tomorrow if you are interested.

Comment: @PhoemueX -- You are correct. Indeed, the $C^\infty$ subatlas will be unique. I believe this is a result by Whitney.

Comment: @PhoemueX: What do you mean by: *This means that there are charts which are $C^\infty$ when considered relative to this sub atlas, but when we consider the chart $ϕ:U \to \partial V$ as a map $ϕ:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$, this map will not (necessarily) be smooth*. Can you give more details?